# published an npm package but installing it just has bare bones files

Tags: javascript, npm

so I have published an npm package but when I installed it, it didn't pull any of the code from my github repo. Instead, it just has the node_modules

```
{
  "name": "asdf",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "asdf",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "got": "^9.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "bin" : { "asdf" : "index.js" },
  "files": [
    "index.js"
    ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/asdf/asdf.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/asdf/asdf/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://asdf"
}
```

What I expected was to have the index.js it pulls from git repo which is public.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the repo. My guess is `index.js` isn't where you think it is. Is it in a directory?

Comment: @mwilson you mean the repo? no its not in a directory, just two files index.js and package.json commited